# ignore a magrittr piped-in value and pass it on

Tags: r, magrittr

Is there a way to use a function inside of a magrittr pipe which is useful for it's side effects (e.g. `assign`) and which simply takes and passes on the piped-in value at the same time?

For example, let's say I have a pipe which is processing a df and for some reason in the middle of it I want to assign a new object while not interrupting the pipe, and perhaps use that object later in the pipe:

```
df <- mtcars %>%
  rename(mp2 = mpg) %>%
  assign("r", 100, envir = environment()) %>%  # error here
  mutate(mpg2 = mp2 * r)
```

Intended behavior would be for the `assign` line to both assign r to the environment and pass on the mtcars from the previous line to the next line without modification.

Comment: Your `assign()` call doesn't make sense. A `%>%` will pass the lefthand value into the first argument of the righthand function. Your `assign()` call isn't expecting a data frame anywhere so the error you're seeing has nothing to with piping, but rather with trying to pipe a data frame into the first argument of `assign()`.

Comment: Right. What I was looking for was a way to do the assign in the middle of the pipe without interrupting it. The `walk`, `{...}`, and `%V%` answers below are all good solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Place the last two statements within {...} like this.  It keeps `r` local to the `{...}` so that after the {...} completes `r` will be cleaned up (i.e. removed) automatically.

```
mtcars %>%
  rename(mp2 = mpg) %>% 
  {
    assign("r", 100, envir = environment()) 
    mutate(., mpg2 = mp2 * r)
  }
```

In this particular case we could have just written:

```
mtcars %>%
  rename(mp2 = mpg) %>% 
  {
    r <- 100
    mutate(., mpg2 = mp2 * r)
  }
```

If you want to add subsequent statements then if they don't involve `r` just put the next `%>%` right after the `}` or if they do involve `r` start a second pipeline nested within the first by putting the `%>%` after the `mutate(...)` within the `{...}` .

Answer (score 2):

There are three approaches, depending on whether the function depends on computations inside your pipe.

**1) The function to be called is independent of the pipe.** In this case, simply call the function before you begin your pipe:

```
assign("r", 100, envir = environment())

df <- mtcars %>%
  rename(mpg2 = mpg) %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = mpg2 * r)
```

**2) The function requires input from the pipe, but you're calling it for its side effect.** This is where the `magrittr::%T>%` pipe pointed out by @Thomas comes in:

```
f <- function(x) {cat( "Calling f on", class(x), "\n")}  # Side effect is printing

df <- mtcars %>%
  rename(mpg2 = mpg) %T>%    ## This pipe is defined inside magrittr package
  f() %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = mpg2 * r)
## Calling f on data.frame
```

**3) The function needs to be applied to every element of the input (such as every column in a data frame), but you need the function for its side effect.** This is the job of `purrr::walk()`:

```
df <- mtcars %>%
  rename(mpg2 = mpg) %>%
  walk(f) %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = mpg2 * r)
## Calling f on numeric
## ...
## Calling f on numeric
```

Comment: I think the idea of the question was that r is supposed to be locally defined in the pipeline.  If it is defined globally before the pipeline runs then we don't need anything special.

Comment: Hm, you may be right. From the phrasing of the question, it's not completely clear to me whether `assign` is just an example of a "side effect" function, or if it's a pivotal component of the requirements. If the goal is to restrict the definition of `r` to the pipeline, then your answer provides a very nice solution. Another alternative is to encapsulate my entire example 1) into a standalone function, which would limit the scope of the `r` definition to its immediate usage in the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, Grothendieck is right -- idea is that r is supposed to be defined inside the pipe--no definitions beforehand. I liked your original `walk` answer before the edits. Is there a way to use the `walk` solution without having `r` defined globally? In some cases global assignment is useful but I can also think of situations where I would prefer to keep it local (original question was ambiguous on this). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to specify a different environment during assignment, but I advocate against the usage of `walk()` for your use case. After posting the original `walk()` solution, I realized that `assign` would be called multiple times (once for each column). This can lead to very inefficient code if you have a large number of columns.

Comment: Personally, I would either go with @G.Grothendieck 's solution, or do something like `mypipe <- function() {r <- 100; mtcars %>% rename(mpg2 = mpg) %>% mutate( mpg2 = mpg2 * r )}`. This way `r` is only visible inside the function and not globally.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps create a 'sink' pipe operator that evaluates the RHS without any connection to the LHS, then returns LHS.

```
`%V%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {rhs; lhs}
```

Note that I believe there's a typo in your original code: `mpg2` won't be defined.

```
df <- mtcars %>%
  rename(mp2 = mpg) %V%
  assign(x = "r", 100, envir = environment()) %>%  
  mutate(mpg2 = mp2 * r)

    mp2 cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg2
1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 2100
2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 2100
3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2280
4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 2140
5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 1870
```